# How to run a function that affects all directives of the same type before running a function for a specific directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I got a menu directive that shows a little dropdown menu. I'm a bit lost on one thing though and that's how to make sure only one menu is open at one time. I would want to run the `am.close` function for all menus and then run the `am.toggle` for the menu that I've clicked.

How can I do this?

Directive:

```
core.directive('amMenu', [function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      wrapper: '@',
      host: '=',
      options: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: './assets/angular/modules/core/directives/actions-menu/am-menu.html',
    controller: 'AmMenuCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'am',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
  };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
core.controller('AmMenuCtrl', [function() {

  var am = this;

  /--- some option arrays here ---/


  am.toggle = function() {
    am.isToggled = !am.isToggled;
  };

  am.close = function() {
    am.isToggled = false;
  };
}]);
```

Template:

```
<div class="am-menu-wrapper" click-outside on-outside="am.close" exceptions="['am-menu-wrapper']">
  <span class="am-toggle am-icon" ng-click="am.toggle()">
    <i class="icon icon-dots-horizontal"></i>
  </span>
  <ul class="am-menu" ng-class="{visible: am.isToggled}">
    <li class="am-item">
      <span class="pull-rights" ng-click="am.close()"><i class="icon icon-dots-horizontal"></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="am-item" ng-repeat="option in am[options].options" ng-bind="option.label" ng-click="option.onClick(host, wrapper)"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions just come into my minds :

1. I think you can use a service to store all the directives' reference, when one of them is clicked, call `am.close` on each of them and call `am.toggle` just on the clicked one.
2. Instead of using nested variable `isToggled` to control the status of the dropdown list, you can use 'document.querySelectorAll('[am-menu]');' to get all directives, and add/remove css class to control the open/closed status

Comment: The second option worked, haven't even thought of that. Thanks!